# How to use JSON-like Objects in PLSQL - APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

This isn't an Oracle APEX specific question, but didn't know if the fact that I'm using APEX presents APIs that may help that native PLSQL does not have. I'm using Oracle database 19c with APEX 19.2.

I have a function that will validate if a password meets specified guidelines. Sometimes I just want to know if the password is valid (Yes or No), other times I will also want to include the validation errors to display back to the user (adding to APEX error stack - i know how to do this).

Based on this, is there a way to return a PLSQL object similar to JSON or JavaScript using PLSQL? If so, how would I build the object in the validate_password PLSQL function? And how would I be able to utilize this object in other PLSQL packages/functions/etc.? Any links to examples or documentation for me to read would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_password(p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN [OBJECT]
```

Where `[OBJECT]`, would take some form of:

```
{ valid: "Y" or "N",
  errors: [
    "Must contain one uppercase",
    "Must contain one lowercase"...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APEX has a package [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/APEX_JSON.html#GUID-11919ED6-CE3D-4497-8733-F56CD27B6BFF) which can be used to build or parse JSON. It is very handy if you are on a version of Oracle Database that does not have native JSON capabilities.

Starting with Oracle Database 12.2, Oracle introduced JSON_OBJECT_T and JSON_ARRAY_T which can assist with parsing and building JSON objects/arrays very easily. [Oracle-Base has a decent article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plsql-object-types-for-json-12cr2) demonstrating some of the functionality of these objects. If you have the option, JSON_OBJECT_T/JSON_ARRAY_T should be used as they will perform much faster than APEX_JSON.

Below are some example functions demonstrating how you can use both options to do some password validation and return the results in the JSON structure you described.

**Example Procedures**

```sql
DECLARE
    l_password   VARCHAR2 (50) := '123';

    FUNCTION validate_password_json (p_password VARCHAR2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        l_output   json_object_t := json_object_t ();
        l_errors   json_array_t := json_array_t ();
    BEGIN
        IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (p_password, '[a-z]')
        THEN
            l_errors.append ('Password must contain a lowercase letter');
        END IF;

        IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (p_password, '[A-Z]')
        THEN
            l_errors.append ('Password must contain an uppercase letter');
        END IF;

        l_output.put ('valid', CASE WHEN l_errors.get_size = 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END);
        l_output.put ('errors', l_errors);
        RETURN l_output.stringify;
    END;

    FUNCTION validate_password_apex (p_password VARCHAR2)
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        l_valid   VARCHAR2 (1) := 'Y';
    BEGIN
        apex_json.initialize_clob_output;
        apex_json.open_object;
        apex_json.open_array ('errors');

        IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (p_password, '[a-z]')
        THEN
            l_valid := 'N';
            apex_json.write ('Password must contain a lowercase letter');
        END IF;

        IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE (p_password, '[A-Z]')
        THEN
            l_valid := 'N';
            apex_json.write ('Password must contain an uppercase letter');
        END IF;

        apex_json.close_array;

        apex_json.write ('valid', l_valid);
        apex_json.close_object;

        RETURN apex_json.get_clob_output;
    END;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('JSON_OBJECT_T/JSON_ARRAY_T Output');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (validate_password_json (l_password));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('---------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('APEX_JSON Output');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (validate_password_apex (l_password));
END;
/
```

**Example Output**

```
JSON_OBJECT_T/JSON_ARRAY_T Output
{"valid":"N","errors":["Password must contain a lowercase letter","Password must contain an uppercase letter"]}
---------------------------------
APEX_JSON Output
{
"errors":[
"Password must contain a lowercase letter"
,"Password must contain an uppercase letter"
]
,"valid":"N"
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, stumbled upon it also after posting my question (didn't use the correct search words initially). Thank you so much for the clear example as well. I will definitely play around with this now.

Comment: something I noticed you return the json as VARCHAR2. Is there a reason to serialize/deserialize the JSON down to a string instead of passing them as / receiving them as JSON_OBJECT_T?

Comment: I was just returning it as a VARCHAR2 because I was printing the results to DBMS_OUTPUT. You can definitely return JSON_OBJECT_T if that suits your needs better

Comment: OK thanks for the quick response. Appreciate your help. Always love to learn something new after years of doing things "the same way" ;)